# How to add images in flutter via CDN

Tags: flutter, cdn, flutter-web

I am new to flutter development and I have some images in my flutter web app, and I want to put the images in some CDN network and fetch it from there. Is this possible in flutter?

I checked google but I could not find anything concrete. Need some guidance. Thanks!

Pseudo Code-

```
  new NetworkImage(CDN LINK)
```

Answer (score 1):

See [the cookbook here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image). But if these images are only used in your flutter application, wouldn't it make more sense just to bundle them along with any other assets and use an `AssetImage`?